# How can I only import the edited ('IMG_E') photos to Windows?

Tags: iphone, windows, photos, data-transfer

I've imported thousands of photos to Windows and I've ended up with thousands of duplicates. :/

It's importing the originals (IMG_001.jpg) and the file containing the edits (IMG_001.aee) but it's also importing the edited version (IMG_E001.jpg) which is the only one I want to keep.

For example, if this was in portrait mode, only the IMG_E001.jpg actually has the portrait mode effect applied to it and I have no need for the original.

The AAE files are simple enough to delete - sort by file type and delete them all... but deleting the originals really isn't so simple, I'm having to manually find each edited file, and then scan for the original and delete it (also hoping I don't accidentally delete the wrong one each time)

Is there a better way to do this please? This is going to take me weeks to sort through, and I'm worried I will accidentally delete some of the wrong files.

Thank you